# Question about Definition, Riemann Sum, Upper\Lower Riemann Sum and Upper\Lower Darboux Sum

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, definition, riemann-sum

Notation:

Riemann sum ${S_{p}}(f)$

Upper/Lower Riemann sum $\overline{S_{p}}(f)$/$\underline{S_{p}}(f)$

Upper/Lower Darboux Sum $U_p(f)$/$L_p(f)$

---

Definition:

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and  p be partition of [a,b]

Riemann sum:

$${S_{p}}(f)=\sum _{i=1}^n\:(x_i-x_{i-1})f(t_i)\text{ where } t_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$$

Upper/Lower Riemann sum:

$$\overline{S_{p}}(f)/\underline{S_{p}}(f)=\sup\{{S_{p}}(f)\}/\inf\{{S_{p}}(f)\}$$

Upper/Lower Darboux sum:

$$U_p(f)/L_p(f)=\sum _{i=1}^n\:(x_i-x_{i-1})\sup\limits _{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)/\sum _{i=1}^n\:(x_i-x_{i-1})\inf\limits _{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)$$

---

Question:

On my text book(maybe most text book), it only defined Riemann sum and Upper/Lower Darboux sum. And I also see some text use Upper/Lower Darboux sum to define Upper/Lower Riemann sum, are they equivalent definitions?
In another word:

$$\sup\{{S_{p}}(f)\}/\inf\{{S_{p}}(f)\}\overset?=\sum _{i=1}^n\:(x_i-x_{i-1})\sup\limits _{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)/\sum _{i=1}^n\:(x_i-x_{i-1})\inf\limits _{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your upper Riemann sum is simply an upper Darboux sum.

Comment: Your last equation (with the question mark) is, in fact, true.  To see this, note that the partition, $p$, is fixed.  The $\sup$ in the upper Riemann sum is being taken over all choices of $t_i \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]$ and $\sup$ breaks down over sums (See "Properties" and also the 2nd bullet from the end here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum ).  It follows that the RHS of your equation is, in fact, equal to the LHS.